# Data structure for make-like programs

Tags: data-structures, graph, makefile, directed-acyclic-graphs

Given a directed acyclic graph *G*, is there a way to represent *G* such that the following operations are all possible in *O(log |G|)* time?

1. Remove a node *N* from *G*. It can be assumed that no edges lead to *N*, but some edges may lead away from *N*. It can be assumed that *N* is marked.
2. Mark a node (all nodes start as unmarked)
3. Return an unmarked node in *G* that has no edges leading to it.

These operations correspond to the basic operations of a *make* like program that computes a complete dependency graph before executing rules:

- (1) corresponds to marking a target as *done*
- (2) corresponds to marking a target as *started*
- (3) corresponds to finding a target that can be started right now as all of its prequisites have been done.

Comment: @harold If you wouldn't delete your answer, it would be able to discuss it. If the accumulated runtime of these operations is O(|G|log|G|), that would be fine, too.

Comment: But it doesn't technically answer the question, does it? It's just the standard algorithm anyway.

Comment: That seems like almost standard topological sorting (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), and the classic algorithms for that are O(|V| + |E|). I'm not sure what you mean by O(|G|), but would that not be good enough for your use case?

Comment: @Ivan Vergiliev Looks like that. I thought it wasn't at first, since my application has an arbitrary delay between the point where a node is started and the point where a node can be removed from *G* but the marking I explained in the question can easily be implemented with the set of all nodes that don't have outgoing nodes.

Comment: @harold Well, it did in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a variant of the topological sorting algorithm discussed in The Art of Computer Programming, vol. 1 (Fundamental Algorithms), sect. 2.2.3 implemented in Go, that implements the required features:

```
package graph

import "os/exec"

// a user of this package shall initialize each node with the command to be
// run and a set of other nodes that can only be executed when this node has
// been finished. It is assumed that no cycles exist.
type Node struct {
    exec.Cmd
    incoming int // populated by Execute()
    Outgoing []Node
}

type Graph struct {
    Nodes []Node
}

// execute a graph
func (g *Graph) Execute() {
    var dispatcher = make(chan *Node)

    for _, n := range g.Nodes {
        for _, nn := range n.Outgoing {
            nn.incoming++
        }
    }

    for _, n := range g.Nodes {
        if n.incoming == 0 {
            go n.run(dispatcher)
        }
    }

    // each node will spawn one task
    for _ = range g.Nodes {
        n := <-dispatcher
        for _, nn := range n.Outgoing {
            nn.incoming--
            if nn.incoming == 0 {
                go n.run(dispatcher)
            }
        }
    }
}

// run the function corresponding to a node and notify when done
func (n *Node) run(dispatcher chan<- *Node) {
    n.Cmd.Run()
    dispatcher <- n
}
```

Instead of a set of undone tasks, this algorithm directly spawns workers and collects them using a channel.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall the running time complexity, but maybe you could use a directed graph (I originally said *tree* but it's possible for some nodes to have multiple parents - I'm not sure how best to represent that)?

To your requirement 3, for the set S of all nodes that have no edge leading to them, what's wrong with creating a "dummy" root node with edges leading to each node without a parent?  This would change requirement 3 to "return an unmarked node in G which has an edge from the root node leading to it".